# Cakephp - multiple views one controller-Function

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

I'm working with CakePHP for a few weeks. I have created with the Console the CRUD functionality and Pagination. For the layout I used the plugin from bootstrap. The website is designed to facilitate a competitive process. 
Now I have a question: In my example, there are different user roles. For a role, we need a function which is used in 16 Views, just every time another table content. But I can not  write the same function 16 times? Thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Add that function in AppController, which is extends by each Controllers.

Example of AppController

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

    function usedInDifferentControllers($param1, $param2){
        //code
    }
}
```

Example of PagesController

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class PagesController extends AppController {
    function action_name(){
        //call the function from  AppController
        $this->usedInDifferentControllers($param1, $param2); 
    }

    //optionally, you can override the method if required for each controller
    function usedInDifferentControllers(){
        parent::usedInDifferentControllers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I said it false: the action which is used in the 16 Views, need just every time another table record. I mean its the same table but another record from this table :/
So I have only one table! the function (action) is always the same.

//Example
table (
firstname,
lastname,
number1,
number2,
number3,
and so on...)

//in the controller
      dosomething(){ }

//in the view
dosomething.ctp (firstname, lastname, number1)
dosomething1.ctp (firstname, lastname, number2)
dosomething2.ctp (firstname, lastname, number3)

At the End I will have a function, which will calculate with this numbers
in an new view :)

I search something like that:

```
 public function index() {
    // 0 CakePHP fetches Group data and its domain

        $groupId=$this->Auth->user('User.role_id');
   if($groupId==1) $this->view='viewA';
   else if($groupId==4) $this->view='ViewB';

    $participants = $this->Participant->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('participants',$this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

But it doesn't works like that:(